# VBA Script to copy and Paste last column of data on multiple sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need a script that takes the last column of data within a workbook and copies and pastes that data in the column immediately to the right. My problem is that I need to do this for multiple, specific sheets in a workbook so I am trying to use a loop and I can't figure out the code to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim sArray
Dim lc As Long

Set sArray = Sheets(Array("sht3", "sht5", "sht7", "sht9", "sht11", "sht13", "sht15", "sht17" _
, "sht19", "sht21", "sht23", "sht25", "sht27", "sht29"))

For Each Sheet In sArray

lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(lc).Copy
Cells(1, lc + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to paste it in every sheet but the one from which you are copying?

Comment: No copy and paste the last column on each sheet individually. In other words copy and paste the last column on each sheet and only that sheet and then do the same thing for each sheet.

Comment: I've answered you with a loop which goes through all the sheets in a workbook without need to declare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question this should solve it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lc As Integer
    Dim sArray As Variant

    Set sArray = Sheets(Array("sht3", "sht5", "sht7", "sht9", "sht11", "sht13", "sht15", "sht17" _
                        , "sht19", "sht21", "sht23", "sht25", "sht27", "sht29"))

    For Each ws In sArray
        With ws
            lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Cells(1, lc).EntireColumn.Copy .Cells(1, lc + 1)
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I adapt this to only look at certain worksheets? I don't want this macro to run on every sheet in the workbook

Comment: @SOJ3 try the answer from SJR if doesn't work, will give you a workaround.

Comment: Hi Damian no luck with yours I get an error at the "next ws" line

Comment: Hi Damian, that is very close but it copied column A and pasted into column B, I need the script to copy and paste on the other spectrum so copy the last column (not the first) and paste into the column to the right.

Comment: This is taking the last column assuming you have data on row 1, if your data starts on another row, change the 1 on `.Cells(1. .Columns.Count)` with the number of the row where your data is

Comment: Ahh I see!! Thank you so much. You are guys are amazing. Still learning the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add sheet references inside your loop so that the correct sheet is being referenced. (Otherwise the active sheet will be referenced, and this doesn't change in your code.)

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim sArray
Dim lc As Long

Set sArray = Sheets(Array("sht3", "sht5", "sht7", "sht9", "sht11", "sht13", "sht15", "sht17" _
                    , "sht19", "sht21", "sht23", "sht25", "sht27", "sht29"))

For Each Sheet In sArray
    lc = Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheet.Columns(lc).Copy
    Sheet.Cells(1, lc + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, this seems to work but it is copying the the first column on the worksheet, I need it to copy the last column on the right. In other words the last column that has data is in column L and I need it to copy and paste the data from column L into column M, but the last column with data in it is different for each sheet

Comment: use my way to copy paste @SOJ3

Comment: Do you have data in the first row of each sheet?

Comment: Thank you SJR, I did not which was my problem. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Below I'm providing two alternatives to loop through specific sheets, to get you started:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Something" Or sht.Name = "Something else" Then 'and so on and so forth...
        'do something
    End If
Next sht
```

or

```
Dim shtCollection As New Collection
Dim sht As Worksheet
With shtCollection
    .Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Something")
    .Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Something else")
    'and so on and so forth...
End With
For Each sht In shtCollection
    'do something
Next sht
```